# Django Haystack ordering

Tags: django, django-haystack

I want to order the posts on my app by the number of likes (in reverse) so I've put this code in search_indexes.py:

```
like = IntegerField(model_attr="like", null=True)
```

and in the model:

```
like = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In the view the code is:

```
context = {
   'var': SearchQuerySet().all().order_by('-like'),
}
```

This seems to order the posts by the number of likes but in this order (ordered by likes):

97 9 9 8 83 7

It would seem like the ordering is only by the first number. How can I fix this? Is this a bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the root of this problem - It was the scheme. At first the field like wasn't an integer, it was a CharField and when I changed it I only rebuilded the index instead of build_solr_schema as it is required.